# Finding $\sum_{k=1}^{p-1}\left\lfloor\frac {k^3}{p} \right\rfloor $

Tags: elementary-number-theory, contest-math, ceiling-and-floor-functions

> Let, $p$ be an odd prime. Find $$\sum_{k=1}^{p-1}\left\lfloor\frac {k^3}{p} \right\rfloor $$

Any hints will be helpful. Thanks.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/123303/discussion-on-question-by-bert-finding-sum-k1p-1-left-lfloor-frac-k3).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** Show that (for $ 1\leq k \leq p-1$, $p$ prime),
$$ \lfloor \frac{ k^3 } {p}  \rfloor + \lfloor \frac{ (p-k)^3 } { p} \rfloor =  p^2 - 3kp + 3k^2 -1 = \frac{k^3}{p} + \frac{ (p-k)^3} {p} - 1$$

**Corollary:** The problem follows by taking the summation and dividing by 2.

> The answer is $\frac{ (p-1)^2p}{4} - \frac{(p-1)}{2} = \frac{1}{4} (p-2)(p-1)(p+1)$

Comment: I proved the hint, but why did you divide by 2? And how did you make the breakup in the first step?

Comment: @Bert A) Because summing the LHS gives twice of what the problem asks for. B1) The difficulty that you run into with the floor function is that you don't know how much you've reduced going from $x$ to $\lfloor x \rfloor$. We've reduced some value between 1/p and 1, but the sum of p-1 such values could be between 1 and p-1. We need to get a better handle on it. The idea scenario is if we could pair terms up, so that we reduce their value by a known quantity.

Comment: In this case, we paired terms up to reduce the value by 1, hence the sum of values lost is (p-1)/2, which is how I arrived at my numerical answer. B2) The goal is to find a pairing/grouping where we reduce the value by an integer amount. Looking at $(k, p-k)$ is common, else we can look at $ (k, (p-1)/2 + k)$, or other variations. Of course, this is "knowing" that there is likely a nice approach.

Comment: @Bert C) I'm not sure what you're asking for. Please elaborate on what you're going for. D) Are you familiar with the concept that $ \sum f(i) = \sum f(n-i)$? Similar to Gauss' trick in summing up AP's. If so, I'm looking at $ \sum f(k) + f(p-k)$ instead of just $ \sum f(k)$.

Comment: So you are essentially summing f(k) twice, and hence you divide by 2?

Comment: @Bert Yes ( Or you can read the tail comment of B1 to see how I arrived at my numerical answer.)

Comment: I got it. Thanks for spending your precious time.

Comment: Hello again. But wolfram gives a different answer for the initial summation!

Comment: @Bert I checked and it seems right. Can you send a link of what you entered?

Comment: Nah, I checked, and apparently I entered the index wrong. Yours is alright.